# Display a single relationship type Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I display neo4j nodes and a unique relationship type linking them?

I have a Neo4j graph, the nodes are linked with multiple relationship types (DODAG, BE, etc..) and I want to display the nodes linked with a specific relationship type without displaying the other relationship links.

When I run

`MATCH p=()-[r:DODAG]->() RETURN p`

I get the nodes linked by the DODAG relationship type, but the graph also displays the other relationships that link these nodes (BE, etc..)

How could I return the same result, but without the other relationships?

Thank you!

Comment: You can check off *Connect result nodes* in the Browser Settings of the console and re-run your query.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning path, return those specific nodes and relationship only:

```
MATCH (a)-[rel:DODAG]->(b)
RETURN a, rel, b
```